# Can I source ksh and expect in the same script?

Tags: unix, ksh, expect

I am trying to use environment variables set by ksh and the expect command in the same script. However, if I try to source both of them, it doesnt work. Is there a way to source ksh and expect in the same script?

Comment: Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help explain your question

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

. /path/to/ksh_stuff.sh
export FOO=bar

# other ksh stuff

expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    source /path/to/expect_stuff.exp
    send_user "FOO is $env(FOO)\n"
    # other expect stuff
END_EXPECT
```

Adding quotes around the here-doc terminator (`<<'END_EXPECT'`) means that the entire here-doc is single quoted, so ksh will not attempt any parameter substitutions on it. This is a effective way to isolate the expect script's variables from ksh.

Answer (score 0):

In Korn shell you dot in the other script, example:

```
. ${other_script}
```

This will run in the same process as the parent script. The other script can see any variables that are defined in the parent script.   If you want to sub-shell (to run an external command), then you will need to export any variables first.

If you want to reference environment variables in your expect script, (those that are exported by a ksh script that runs expect in a subshell) then your expect script needs to reference a global array `env` . For example if your ksh script exports MYPATH variable then subshells to expect, the expect might reference `$env(MYPATH)`

Comment: But sourcing the other script will just run it in KSH as well, wont it? This defeats the purpose since the second script doesnt recognize the EXPECT command when sourcing ksh

Comment: The issue is I need to use environment variables that are set in KSH in my expect script. Can I pass these as parameters?

Comment: Updated answer to reference expect $env array